# Need an alternative for \usepackage[none]hyphenat

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem. When i want to use hyphenat package, the `breaklines=true` on mmacells package will not working. But it will work if i delete the hyphenat package. And i don't want to delete my hyphenat package because i really need this to get rid of word separator dash after breaking text to the next line.
I mean like this:
[image: word separator]

So, how to use hyphenat and do `breaklines=true` at the same time? Or maybe you have another alternative for hyphenat?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmacells, lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\begin{mmaCell}[morefunctionlocal={R},morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
Integrate[ Limit[E^(\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}t)/(R-\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}),R \(\pmb{\to}\)\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}],\{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\xi}\)},-\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)},0\}]
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
0   
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morefunctionlocal={R},morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
\{Integrate[E^((\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\pi}\)}- 2\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\theta}\)})/\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\pi}\)} (\mmaUnd{R} t +1)),\{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\theta}\)},\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\pi}\)}/2,\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\pi}\)}\}], Limit[(\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\pi}\)}(1 - E^(-(R t +1))))/(2(R t+1)),R \(\pmb{\to}\)\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)},Assumptions\(\pmb{\to}\)t>0]\}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
\{\mmaFrac{\(\pi\)-\mmaSup{e}{-1-R t} \(\pi\)}{2+2 R t},0\} 
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
\{Integrate[1/t E^(-\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}) Log[\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}-t], \{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)},t,\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}\},Assumptions\(\pmb{\to}\)t>0], Integrate[-1/t E^(-\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}) Log[\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}],\{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)},t, \mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}\},Assumptions\(\pmb{\to}\)t>0]\}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
\{-\mmaFrac{\mmaSup{e}{-t} EulerGamma}{t},-\mmaFrac{Gamma[0,t]+\mmaSup{e}{-t} Log[t]}{t}\}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
Integrate[1/t  E^(-\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}) Log[(\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}-t)/\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)}], \{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\lambda}\)} ,t,\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}\},Assumptions\(\pmb{\to}\)t>0]
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelst={breaklines=true}]{Output}
\mmaFrac{1}{t}(EulerGamma+i (-1+\mmaSup{e}{-t}) \(\pi\)+t \mmaSup{Hypergeometric1F1}{(1,0,0)}[1,2,-t]-\mmaSup{HypergeometricU}{(1,0,0)}[0,0,-t])
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelst={breaklines=true},moredefined={f1}]{Input}
f1=-\mmaFrac{\mmaSup{\mmaDef{e}}{-t} EulerGamma}{t}-\mmaFrac{Gamma[0,t]+\mmaSup{\mmaDef{e}}{-t} Log[t]}{t}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelst={breaklines=true}]{Output}
-\mmaFrac{\mmaSup{e}{-t} EulerGamma}{t}-\mmaFrac{Gamma[0,t]+\mmaSup{e}{-t} Log[t]}{t}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[moredefined={ff1},morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
ff1=\mmaFrac{1}{t}(EulerGamma+\mmaDef{i} (-1+\mmaSup{\mmaDef{e}}{-t}) \mmaDef{\(\pmb{\pi}\)}+t \mmaSup{Hypergeometric1F1}{(1,0,0)}[1,2,-t]-\mmaSup{HypergeometricU}{(1,0,0)}[0,0,-t])
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}[morelst={breaklines=true}]{Output}
\mmaFrac{1}{t}(EulerGamma+i (-1+\mmaSup{e}{-t}) \(\pi\)+t \mmaSup{Hypergeometric1F1}{(1,0,0)}[1,2,-t]-\mmaSup{HypergeometricU}{(1,0,0)}[0,0,-t])
\end{mmaCell}
 \newpage\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you not want hyphenation? you can prevent that in many ways eg simply use `\raggedright` (justifying text with no hyphenation can not work well) or  set `\hyphenpenalty=10000`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because i'm using mmacells package and need to break the code avoiding overflowed text. If i use hyphenat, the code will not doing breaklines.

Comment: Maybe change the hyphenation character? With `fontspec`, you can `\setmainfont[HyphenChar="200B]` to make the hyphenation character a zero-width space.

Comment: @Davislor sadly i use pdfLaTeX and it said requires XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is wonderful! Seems work, but haven't tried to check if the hyphenation is correct or not.

Comment: If you want to disable all hyphenaton, see [the FAQ.](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff) Whenever I do this, I load font expansion with `microtype` and increase `\emergencystretch`, to mitigate the damage.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you so much for your help and Mr. David also.  :)